# How to do deal solve linearmodels.panel.PanelOLS error " Cannot set name on a level of a MultiIndex. Use 'MultiIndex.set_names' instead. "

Tags: python

I am running PanelOLS on a panel dataset. I use the set_index function to set time and entity indices. But I cannot resolve the error message:

> Cannot set name on a level of a MultiIndex. Use 'MultiIndex.set_names' instead.

I am using the example and dataset in https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/devel/panel/examples/examples.html:

```
from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel
import pandas as pd
data = wage_panel.load()
year = pd.Categorical(data.year)
data = data.set_index(["nr", "year"])
data["year"] = year
print(wage_panel.DESCR)
print(data.head())
```

Then I execute the exact same piece of code as in that example:

```
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
exog_vars = ["expersq", "union", "married", "year"]
mod = PanelOLS(data.lwage, exog, entity_effects=True)
fe_res = mod.fit()
print(fe_res)
```

But this ends up in this error:

> Cannot set name on a level of a MultiIndex. Use 'MultiIndex.set_names' instead.'

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try using `MultiIndex.set_names`?

Comment: I didn't. The problem is that my data format is exactly what it should be! the same as the example link I attached. Moreover, I don't actually know what MultiIndex.set_names would do, since the indexes in the dataframe already have names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem. Actually, I ran my code a few days ago and it worked. The same piece of code does not work today. Try updating 'linearmodels' (pip install --upgrade linearmodels). It works for me.

Comment: Thanks! this worked! I can't believe I spent two days on this!

Comment: I'm glad it helps!